# Why does this Jade plant have small leaves when compared to other Jade plants?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, succulents, jade

[image]
[image]
[image]

And more importantly, how do I take care of this plant? This is a succulent plant, so it needs less water, right or wrong? On one site it says that I need to water it every time the top soil gets dry. I am confused as to how to take care of this plant. How do I take care of it and why the leaves are short.

Comment: I have been growing these plants for years and I find them to be great plants
for Bonsai trees. I tried the large leaf plant, but have a special liking, for
the smaller leaf for Bonsai trees. Planting is easy.I snip a branch off the plant and place it in a pot with a mix of potting mix and water it and let it grow. Making it into a Bonsai tree is the fun part. If you want to know how
to do it, let me Know.

Comment: @normjohnson Sure. I will try it one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade plant is actually Crassula, usually Crassula ovata, but there are other varieties such as Crassula rupestris; even with Crassula ovata, there are varieties with slightly smaller leaves, variegated leaves and so on, so its possible you have a slightly different variety from the basic Crassula ovata.

From the photo supplied with your other question on this plant regarding pot size, its also possible the plant is etiolated and has not had sufficient nutrients or the right conditions for the leaves to have achieved their proper size, so I'm not sure which of these is correct - its being a sub variety or just not kept in optimum conditions.

In terms of watering, these plants are prone to fungal diseases if kept too wet, but they still need water, particularly in summer, so they need good, free draining soil in a pot with good drainage. Water when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, water well, allow to drain freely, and water again only when the soil feels just dry to the touch. They need bright daylight but be careful about sunlight - if they're used to it already, they do very well in sun, but one that's grown without sun may burn when first exposed. More information regarding watering and general care here

http://www.thegardenhelper.com/crassulaargentea.htm

I know the link refers to Crassula argentea, but that's just an alternative name for Crassula ovata, they're the same plant. Note that, although there is a recommendation for fertilizing regularly during the summer months, the plant will cope just fine with less feeding than is suggested. Recommendations regarding fertilizing are based on optimum rather than 'average' care.

Comment: What about watering in winter? Also, can you please guide me to how to water it well? this is currently how I water my "Song of India" plant: I fill a bottle of tap water and let it rest for 24 hours at least. Then I water 500ml of the water and when the water drains out(in a minute) then after 10-15 minutes, I again water it with the remaining 500ml water. Is this how I water this Jade plant too?

Comment: Guidance on watering is in the link...

Comment: Same goes for "Song of India"?

Comment: Nope, they need to dry out a bit between waterings, see link here http://www.houseplant411.com/houseplant/variegated-dracaena-reflexa-grow-care-advice

Comment: No, no. I mean, I only water when more than 50% of the soil is dry. But when I water it, I give it at least a litre of water.

Comment: If its a large pot, that's what I do - wait till its on the dry side at the top and then give a good soak, as you've described

Answer (score 7):

This plant is not a Crassula! It is a Portulacaria afra, commonly called Spekboom or Elephant Bush in South Africa, which is where it originates. It is extremely drought tolerant, but can also grow quite fast and very lush under kinder conditions.  In Adelaide, Australia (where I live)  you can plant it in your garden as long as the soil drains well in the winter.  In the ground the plant can easily reach 3 metres in height, but it takes pruning quite well so the size can be managed easily.  It likes full sun, more sun, and more sun!

Here is a link for more information:
           http://www.magiminiland.org/Portulacaria.html

It is an amazing plant - one of mine is over 50 years old!

Comment: I'm quite sure you could be right. Raised the case in https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/32992/how-to-differentiate-between-protulacaria-and-crassula

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  Another common name is dwarf jade, which just adds to the confusion.